# How to satisfy two conditions to extract data from a dataframe. one if the columns are > 0 and if that condition satisfies 20% of the rows for each

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

the condition is that the values in a column are more than 0 for at least 20 % of the rows

```
condition = df3[df3 > 0]

for value in df3:
    if condition is 0.2*(df3.iloc[1:, 1:]):
        #subset only columns that satisfy the condition
     
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(0)


df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((4, 10))-0.8)

larger_zero_count = (df3 > 0).sum(axis=1)

mask = (larger_zero_count / df3.columns.size) <= 0.2

df_selection = df3[mask]
```

Comment: How do you then subset only the rows that satisfy the condition as a new dataframe?

Comment: df3_condition = df3[df3.columns[((df3 > 0).sum() / df3.index.size) > 0.2]], this worked!

Comment: I have extended my example with real numbers to demonstrate

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate with the `mean` to get the proportion of `True` and compare to 0.2 (20%):

```
df3[df3.gt(0).mean(axis=1).gt(0.2)]
```